viewport overlays for grease pencil are not visible
I am new to blender and currently running blender version 4.2,
I tried to enable canvas for my grease pencil object but I couldn't find the canvas option in viewport overlays,
I also checked the documentation, it says grease pencil object needs to be selected to enable grease pencil options but I am not able to enable it even after selecting grease pencil object.
Please tell me if there is anything I am doing wrong


When you have a Grease Pencil object selected, a Grease Pencil menu appears next to the Viewport Overlays drop-down. The icon is two squares connected by a looping line. The Canvas option has been moved into this menu.

